# how to access custom annotation values in spring aspect

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-aspects

I am trying to access the custom annotation values from jointCut. But I couldn't find a way.

My sample code :

```
@ComponentValidation(input1="input1", typeOfRule="validation", logger=Log.EXCEPTION)
public boolean validator(Map<String,String> mapStr) {
    //blah blah
}
```

Trying to access `@Aspect` class.

But, i didnt see any scope to access values.

Way i am trying to access is below code

```
CodeSignature codeSignature = (CodeSignature) joinPoint.getSignature(); 
String[] names = codeSignature.getParameterNames();
MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getStaticPart().getSignature();
Annotation[][] annotations = methodSignature.getMethod().getParameterAnnotations();
Object[] values = joinPoint.getArgs();
```

i didnt see any value returns input = input1. how to achieve this.

Comment: Can you provide all the code including the entire custom validation

Comment: Hi, I am also in my learning phase of custom annotation with aspectj. Can you please provide me a demo of how to use custom annotation ? I am new with spring aspectj. Any help will be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the answer by *Jama Asatillayev* is correct from a plain Java perspective, it involves reflection.

But the question was specifically about Spring AOP or AspectJ, and there is a much simpler and more canonical way to bind matched annotations to aspect advice parameters with AspectJ syntax - without any reflection, BTW.

```java
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

import my.package.ComponentValidation;

@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    @Before("@annotation(validation)")
    public void myAdvice(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint, ComponentValidation validation) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint + " -> " + validation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting values, use below:

```
ComponentValidation validation = methodSignature.getMethod().getAnnotation(ComponentValidation.class);
```

you can call `validation.getInput1()`, assuming you have this method in `ComponentValidation` custom annotation.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you have defined a method in Annotation interface like below :

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AspectParameter {
    String passArgument() default "";
}
```

then you can access the class and the method values in the aspect like below :

```
@Slf4j
@Aspect
@Component
public class ParameterAspect {

    @Before("@annotation(AspectParameter)")
    public void validateInternalService(JoinPoint joinPoint, AspectParameter aspectParameter) throws Throwable {    
        String customParameter = aspectParameter.passArgument();
    }
}
```