# Spring AOP @Around access the value of @annotation

Tags: spring, annotations, aop, spring-aop, audit

I have a custom annotation as,

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface XAudit {
    AuditActionType action();
}
```

I am using this annotation on some method as following,

```
@XAudit(action = "REGISTRATION")
public RegistrationDTO register(UserDetail detail) {
    //Logic
    return dto;
}
```

I am capturing event in aspect as following,

```
@Around(value = "@annotation(XAudit)")
public Object postAuditEvent(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, XAudit xAudit) throws Throwable {

        String action = xAudit.action();  //Accessing Action for logic decision making  

        Object result = joinPoint.proceed();

        //audit processing logic

        return result;
}
```

The @Around advice works well with only **ProceedingJoinPoint** argument. If passing **XAudit** as 2nd argument, it throws following error,

```
 Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setObjectPostProcessor' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut 
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:204)
            at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:238)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:535)
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
```

I need to use **xAudit** inside aspect in order to access **action** of **XAudit**. Kindly share some pointers on how can I access the value of @XAudit inside @Around Aspect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31189098/how-to-access-custom-annotation-values-in-spring-aspect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo in the `@Around(value = "@annotation(XAudit)")` , it should be `xAudit` ( x is lower case)

Try : `@Around(value = "@annotation(xAudit)")`

Also , to get the action value from annotation you need to use `xAudit.action()` and not `xAudit.getAction()`.

Complete code would be as follows

```java
@Component
@Aspect
public class XAuditAspect {
    @Around(value = "@annotation(xAudit)")
    public Object postAuditEvent(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, XAudit xAudit) throws Throwable {
            String action = xAudit.action();  //Accessing Action for logic decision making
            Object result = joinPoint.proceed();
            //audit processing logic
            System.out.println(xAudit.action());
            return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Well, the class name XAudit (uppercase) was working fine as far as I was not passing XAudit xAudit in aspect method. However, if I pass this argument in method, then I'll need to use variable name xAudit (lowercase) like you pointed . And thanks for pointing at getAction() typo. I've corrected it.