# How to make a Rest API call inside a custom annotation?

Tags: java, rest, annotations

I want to make a REST API call which return a boolean value as a part of the custom annotation.

Sample Code :

```
**@CustomAnnotation
public String myMethod(){
 // my implementation
}**
```

Only if the boolean value from the REST call is true, the method "myMethod must get triggered and implementation should happen else throw an exception similar to @NotNull .
I was wondering if this is possible, if yes someone please help me out.

Comment: any specific purpose of making it annotation , you can also make it as simple method which return true or false

Answer (score 0):

you can create a simple custom annotation without worrying about code to call rest.
For executing rest call code ->

Read about how to apply aspect oriented programming.

Basically using aop (apsect oriented programming), you can write a code such that for any method which is annotated with your custom annotation, *you wish to execute some piece of code before calling your method*.

**To do this in spring**

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface CustomAnnotation {
    String value() default "";
}

@Pointcut(value = "@annotation(CustomAnnotation)")  // full path to CustomAnnotation class
public void abc() {
}

@Around("abc()")
public Object executeSomePieceOfCode(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {

        System.out.println("this executes before calling method");

        // YOUR CODE TO CALL REST API
        boolean responseFromRestCall = true;  // this flag is set based on response from rest call

        if(responseFromRestCall) {
            // this excutes your method
            Object obj = joinPoint.proceed();
            MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
            Method method = signature.getMethod();

            CustomAnnotation myAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);
            String value = myAnnotation.value();
            System.out.println("value : + " + value);
            return obj;
        } else {
            // currently throwing RuntimeException. You can throw any other custom exception.
            throw new RuntimeException();
        }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. 

This is my customAnnotation code : 
***
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Custom {
    AnnotationValue value();
}
***
where "AnnotationValue" is an enum defined for my implementation. Now how can I obtain the parameter passed in the value() variable into my REST call code of AOP

Comment: While this answer is correct , a better way to obtain the annotation details can be found in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62299322/4214241) to another question. @SahilGarg you may modify the answer to avoid the reflection